# Assign different access to artifact feeds for PATs of same user

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps Artifacts to store private python builds. The projects, code base, and pipelines are all hosted by a different provider, not Azure DevOps.
I have a user account with full privileges. I have set up a PAT that is used to automatically publish builds from my pipelines to multiple different feeds in the same project. I would now like to allow external, but not public, access to download/read **one** of my feeds but not the others. I was thinking this could be achieved by creating a different PAT with appropriate permissions on that one feed but I can not seem to find a way to define what feed the PAT has access to.

I then thought I could set up a second user, using the '+' notation in gmail, e.g. `my_email+external_access@gmail.com` but Azure DevOps does not think email addresses that contain a '+' are valid so that does not work either.

**Example**

```
PAT 1: Can download and publish python packages on Feed A and B
PAT 2: Can download python packages from Feed A, can not access Feed B at all.
```

Is there a way to achieve this without setting up a new email address for the second user, creating users for ALL external parties, or giving public access to the feed I want to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this without setting up a new email address for the second user, creating users for ALL external parties, or giving public access to the feed I want to share?

I am afraid there is no such way to achieve this without setting up a new email address for the second user.

That is because when we set permissions on a feed, the principal to be set is a user or a group, and we could not add a PAT as the subject of the permission.

At present, we can only set the permissions for PAT to read, write, write and manage Packaging, but not specifically set the permissions for a specific feed. This part of the functionality needs to be assigned to the user principal.

So, if you have different permissions for feeds, the best way is using two accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this only with a second user. The PAT says what actions are allowed, but the final user-permission is set in the feed seetings. So I think you would need a second user.

Maybe you should consider not to use your user for publishing the builds. This can be done by the pipeline itself. Then you would be able to modify the user-permissions in the feeds.

Comment: Thank you for the info.
I will clarify in the question that I am NOT using Azure DevOps for my code base or pipelines, only for the artifacts. So I do need a PAT that publishes to the feeds.